# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in my Django signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-3.0

I have the following Django signal which basically triggers the signal to increase the points of my previous records in my postgres db by 5 when a new record is saved, but my Django signal saves the changes to 1 previous record and I get the error `RecursionError: Maximum recursion depth exceeded`

```
# models.py

from django.db.models.signals import post_save    

class Task(models.Model):
    ....


def update_points(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    qs = Task.objects.filter(status='Active')

    for task in qs:
        task.points = task.points + 5
        task.save()
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using the .save() method to save the updated records in my db after a new record has been inserted.

Comment: The `task.save()` likely triggers the *same* signal (and thus keeps triggering that signal).

Comment: Aha! So, instead of the task.save(), how should I update those previous records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely the `point.save()` triggers the same signal. So your signal triggers that signal, and thus this results in endless recursion.

You can update the value with a query in bulk:

```
from django.db.models import F 

def update_points(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Task.objects.filter(status='Active').update(points=F('points')+5)
```

This will not only circument the signalling problem, it will furthermore make a query in *bulk*, and is thus more efficient.

Note that if you `post_save`, then the `Task` that was just added, will be part of the `QuerySet`. Perhaps you want to exclude that `Task`. In that case, we thus can implement this as:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def update_points(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Task.objects.filter(~Q(pk=instance.pk), status='Active').update(
            points=F('points')+5
        )

post_save.connect(update_points, sender=Task)
```

Comment: Correct! I want to exclude that newly added task.

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem. I was facing the same issue and find your solution here after lot of google search :)